# Replace consecutive identical values from excel column using python dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As seen in the first table with fact values beneath units are mentioned and the consecutive "Numbered" values should be replaced with blank preserving text values and boolean values in column.
[image]

The required output can be something similar as follow:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? And what error is stopping you? And why using dataframes?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I am not bound to using dataframes. if you know of any better approach you can share. I am actually new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mask` and `shift`:

```
print(df.mask(df.shift() == df).fillna(''))
```